# Plugins for WordPress not installing on Bluemix

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, ibm-cloud

I am trying to make a WordPress site on Bluemix. I need a specific theme and plugin for my site. I used [wpackagist](https://wpackagist.org/) to grab the lines of code I needed to add in my `composer.json` file. I went into my Bluemix dashboard, clicked edit code, added the lines from wpackagist into the requirements block of code (the code below) and then hit the play button (tried to post pic with post but not enough reputation) However, when I went to my Bluemix site, the plugin and theme were not installed. I looked at the `composer.lock` file and it doesn't look like the theme and plugin are in that file. I have seen places that I need to run a composer update or a push, but I am not sure how. Thanks!

```
"require": {
        "ext-gd"                                      : "*",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress"                        : "*",
        "ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-objectstorage"          : "~2.1.1",
        "ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-config"                 : "dev-master",
        "wpackagist-plugin/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates": "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified": "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/wp-super-cache"            : "*",
        "wpackagist-theme/twentyfourteen"             : "*",
        "wpackagist-theme/twentyfifteen"             : "*",
        "wpackagist-theme/twentysixteen"               : "*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/eventbrite-services": "1.3.1",
        "wpackagist-theme/eventbrite-venue": "1.3.0"
    },
```

Comment: I took another look at my composor.lock and composor.json files and after I hit the triangular run button I actually did have the theme and plugin in the files. However when I went to my wordpress application, I still did not have the plugin or theme

Answer (score 1):

I believe I solved my own problem! I did not realize that after you make your changes to the composer file that you then had to go onto Wordpress and install the plugin and theme. I was assuming they would just automatically pop up. Lesson learned!

It is a little confusing since the warning still pops up that it will delete any plugins and themes but I guess that warning is only for users who did not make changes to the composer file. Hope my struggles help someone else!